# Why is it necessary to provide full path for partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET MVC and I've got a question which I hope you guys can help me with. I have two simple controllers. One main controller and one for a partial view. In the partial view controller I have the following snippet

```
public PartialViewResult PartialSection()
{  
   //query for partial view model

   return PartialView("MyPartialView", viewModel);
}
```

then on the main view I do

```
@Html.Action("PartialSection", "MyPartialController")
```

That above throws the following error:

> The partial view '_MyPartialView' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.

If I change the code in my partial view controller and provide the full path to the partial as

```
return PartialView("~/Views/Common/_MyPartialView.cshtml", viewModel);
```

Then I don't get any errors and the partial view is rendered as expected.

So my question is why do I have to provide the full path to the `PartialView` when calling it from a different controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass complete path because you are using your custom folder instead of using existing folders which framework uses to get the view.

If you place your view **_MyPartialView.cshtml** under folder **Views >> MyPartial >>** then you will not need to write the complete path, but as you have created a new folder name **Common** framework does not know that it have to look in that folder as well when a View is asked to be returned.

By default the framework only looks in two locations for the View file.

**1)** Folder against the controller named directory inside **Views** Folder

**2)** In **Shared** folder in the **Views** directory

If you don't want to do that and want to keep that View in **Common** folder in that case you can have to tell the framework to look in your custom folders as well.

You can register your custom folders to be looked for PartialViews in the `Application_Start` event in `Global.asax`:

```
RazorViewEngine razorEngine = ViewEngines.Engines.OfType<RazorViewEngine>().FirstOrDefault();
if (razorEngine != null)
{
   var newPartialViewFormats = new[] 
                              { 
                                "~/Views/Common/{0}.cshtml"
                              };
   razorEngine.PartialViewLocationFormats = razorEngine.PartialViewLocationFormats.Union(newPartialViewFormats).ToArray();
}
```

You can look at this [blogpost for details.](http://developmentpassion.blogspot.nl/2014/10/aspnet-mvc-adding-custom-direcotry-for.html)

Comment: Better yet: just put the Common views on the shared folder. Use the convention and be happy.

Comment: Thank you for this.. it's helped me gain a better understanding :)

Comment: @EduardoMolteni yes but sometimes we want to organize our Views differently for some reason, so that Shared folder does not ends up with a big list of views

Answer (score 0):

Remove Controller from MyPartialController

so instead of

```
@Html.Action("PartialSection", "MyPartialController")
```

try

```
@Html.Action("PartialSection", "MyPartial")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but @EʜsᴀɴSᴀᴊᴊᴀᴅ [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36285847/3793448) solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do as below:

```
public PartialViewResult PartialSection()
{  
   //query for partial view model

   return PartialView("_MyPartialView", viewModel);
}
```

And call as below:

```
@Html.Action("PartialSection", "MyPartial")
```